# Select rows which do not have duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following SQL table:

```
+--------------+
| Account      |
+--------------+
|    11100011  | 
|    11100012  | 
|    11100013  |  
|    11100014  | 
|    11100011  |  
|    11100012  | 
|    11100015  | 
+--------------+
```

What I need is to make a select query with rows that do not have any duplicates in this table (i.e. removing both duplicated rows), so query result will look like this

```
+--------------+
| Account      |
+--------------+
|    11100013  |  
|    11100014  | 
|    11100015  |
+--------------+
```

How can I do this in tsql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select account
from 
table
group by account
having count(*)=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Account
FROM table_name_in_your_database;
```

General this query is used for selecting distinct elements in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
select * from table_name group by account having count(*)<=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Window Function also we get the same result

```
SELECT Account FROM
(
SELECT Account,
     COUNT(Account)OVER(Partition by Account ORDER BY Account) AS DistinctCnt 
FROM cte
)
DT WHERE DT.DistinctCnt=1
```

Result

```
Account
--------
11100013
11100014
11100015
```